# Combining javascript code with different selector IDs correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have about 30 selectors with different IDs example code with which I provided below

```js
document.getElementById("selector-1").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("btn-1").href = "/?add-to-cart=" + this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-product') + "&" + "variation_id=" + this.value + "/";
}

document.getElementById("selector-2").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("btn-2").href = "/?add-to-cart=" + this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-product') + "&" + "variation_id=" + this.value + "/";
}

document.getElementById("selector-3").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("btn-3").href = "/?add-to-cart=" + this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-product') + "&" + "variation_id=" + this.value + "/";
}
```

Could you please let me know how I can combine all this into something more universal, so as not to bring all the code every time with different IDs, because I see that this is very unoptimized code at the moment. Unfortunately, my knowledge is not enough to refactor this into something more effective.
Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not seeing the HTML (so I could use `closest` for example) you can try delegation from the nearest static container (here I have to use document, again since I do not see your HTML)

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id.startsWith("selector-")) {
    const id = tgt.id.replace("selector-", "btn-");
    document.getElementById(id).href = "/?add-to-cart=" + tgt.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-product') + "&variation_id=" + tgt.value + "/";
  }
})
```

Alternatively get the value on click:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id.startsWith("btn-")) {
    const id = tgt.id.replace("btn-", "selector-");
    const sel = document.getElementById(id);
    tgt.href = "/?add-to-cart=" + sel.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-product') + "&variation_id=" + sel.value + "/";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document query selector to match elements based on the presence or value of a given attribute, Id's included. Since all the functions are the same using a simple css match like:

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='selector']")));
```

```html
<div id="selector-1">1</div>
<div id="selector-2">2</div>
<div id="selector-3">3</div>
```

And then iterating over array to add what you want to the elements should suffice.

Comment: I strongly suggest [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65700911/295783)